# i want to create a select for batterybrand and list of all battery types of all battery

Tags: reactjs

I'm hoping you can assist me with a coding issue I've been facing. I'm trying to create a list and a sub-list, but I'm experiencing difficulty with the second list not being visible when clicked. I've been working on this issue since this morning and would appreciate some guidance.

Additionally, I would like to change the color of the outline text area, specifically the border color of the text area. Would you happen to have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Lastly, I would appreciate it if you could review the UI and provide any feedback or suggestions that you may have.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import "./form.css";

export const BatteryDetails = ({ formData, setForm, navigation }) => {
  const { brand, btype, srno } = formData;
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  // Define options for Battery Brand and Sub-Brand
  const brandOptions = [
    {
      name: "EXIDE",
      btype: ["Exide1", "Exide2", "Exide3"],
    },
    {
      name: "AMARON",
      btype: ["Amron1", "Amron2", "Amron3"],
    },
    {
      name: "POWERZONE",
      btype: ["Powerzone1", "Powerzone2", "Powerzone3"],
    },
  ];

  const handleValidation = () => {
    let formIsValid = true;
    let newErrors = {};

    if (!brand) {
      formIsValid = false;
      newErrors["brand"] = "Battery brand is required";
    }

    if (!btype) {
      formIsValid = false;
      newErrors["btype"] = "Battery Type is required";
    }

    if (!srno) {
      formIsValid = false;
      newErrors["srno"] = "Battery Sr.No is required";
    }

    setErrors(newErrors);
    return formIsValid;
  };

  const handleBrandChange = (e) => {
    const selectedBrand = e.target.value;
    const selectedBrandObject = brandOptions.find(
      (b) => b.name === selectedBrand
    );
    setForm({
      ...formData,
      brand: selectedBrand,
      btype: selectedBrandObject.btype[0],
    });
  };

  const handlebtypeChange = (e) => {
    setForm({ ...formData, btype: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (handleValidation()) {
      navigation.next();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xs">
      <h3>Battery Details</h3>
      <div className="form-wrapper">
        <TextField
          label="Battery Brand"
          name="brand"
          value={brand}
          onChange={handleBrandChange}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          autoComplete="off"
          fullWidth
          error={!!errors["brand"]}
          helperText={errors["brand"]}
          select // Add select attribute to render as a select input
        >
          {brandOptions.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.name} value={option.name}>
              {option.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </TextField>
        <TextField
          label="Battery Type"
          name="btype"
          value={btype}
          onChange={handleBtypeChange}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          autoComplete="off"
          fullWidth
          error={!!errors["btype"]}
          helperText={errors["btype"]}
          select // Add select attribute to render as a select input
        >
          {type &&
            typeOptions
              .find((b) => b.name === type)
              .btype.map((option) => (
                <option key={option} value={option}>
                  {option}
                </option>
              ))}
        </TextField>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
          <Button
            color="neutral"
            variant="contained"
            style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
            onClick={() => navigation.previous()}
          >
            Back
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleNext}
            style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#ff3131" }}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the handlebtypeChange function. In the TextField component for "Battery Type", the onChange attribute is calling handleBtypeChange, but the function name defined is handlebtypeChange.

Comment: checked not that error